# Angular directive and Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning Angular and trying to use it with [Isotope.js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). However I cannot get it working. Here is my code (also on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7e2g37wL/1/)):

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <note></note>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('note', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div class="note" ng-repeat="note in notes">{{note.content}}</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var notes = document.getElementsByClassName("note");
            console.log("notes in DOM: ", notes);
            var iso = new Isotope(element[0], {
                itemSelector: '.note',
                layoutMode: 'masonry'
            });
            console.log(iso.items);
        }
    };
});
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.notes = [{
        "content": "Hello World!"
    }, {
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    }];
});
```

Why isotope has empty array of elements (`console.log(iso.items);` shows"[]") ? It looks like it couldn't find them (with selector ".note"), but they are already attached to DOM (look at `console.log("notes in DOM: ", notes);`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just running after it compiles, you can see a simple $timeout loads it

In a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7e2g37wL/3/)

```
$timeout(function () {
    var iso = new Isotope(element[0], {
        itemSelector: '.note',
        layoutMode: 'masonry'
     });
},0);
```

There is probably a better solution but it really just has to wait until its there.

Comment: Do you have a better solution in mind? $timeout looks a bit ugly to me.

Comment: Since a couple years have passed, and things have changed a bit, I wonder if you could use a component instead of directive, and then do this work in the $postLink hook function instead of using timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to look up the note class in your `document` before the linker has inserted the element into the DOM. Try looking it up on `element` instead of document, and you should have more luck!

You can use jqLite or jQuery (if it's in your project) to access the element.

Comment: but look at first 2 lines in 'link' function: `var notes = document.getElementsByClassName("note");
            console.log("notes in DOM: ", notes);` - in the console I can see those elements with "note" class, so it looks like they are already inserted to the DOM. Am I wrong somewhere?